# C# .NET Windows Forms - Binding 3 Tables with each other in Multiple (3) DataGridView (Master/Detail/Detail)

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, master-detail, bindingsource

A picture is worth a 1000 words.

First of all I am C# / Windows Forms / .NET / SQL Server newbie. I have tried to look and figure it out by myself before posting as well as googling and searching on SO. My ultimate goal is to make this work. So a help in a form of Guidance/Tutorial/Suggestion is most welcome.

Please ask me for clarification if needed before marking this question as unfit, inconvenient, ineligible or not well declared or unclarified.

[image: 3 DataGridViews (dg1-Kupci, dg2-Narudžbe, dg3-Stavke Narudžbe)]

I have a problem in relating Customers (Kupci from the picture) with Orders (Narudžbe from the picture).

I have used guidance from this [Master/Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c12c1kx4(v=vs.100).aspx) article from msdn.microsoft.com

And it works when I relate to 2 tables. When I click on SalesOrderID (from SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader) I can relate to SalesOrderID (from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail).

Problem with this approach appears when I want to relate to 3 tables (bond with each other). I want first to click on Customers (Kupci) in order to get to specific SalesOrderID's for that Customer and then I want to click on specific SalesOrderID to see it's OrderItemDetails (Stavke Narudžbe from the picture)

My DataGridViews from the picture are named dg1 (Kupci DataGridView), dg2 (Narudžbe DataGridView), dg3 (Stavke Narudžbe DataGridView) respectively from up to bottom.

Here is my code:

```
namespace InvoiceSQL {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    private BindingSource masterBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    private BindingSource detailsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    private BindingSource dg3BindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dg1.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
        dg2.DataSource = detailsBindingSource;
        dg3.DataSource = dg3BindingSource;
        getData();

        dg1.AutoResizeColumns();
        dg2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        dg3.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

    }

    private void getData()
    {
        try
        {
            //Odredi string za konekciju
            String connectionString = "omitted info, but working!";
            //Konektuj se na bazu
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            //Odredi novi dataset
            DataSet data = new DataSet();
            data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            //Dodaj podatke iz tabele Kupci u DataSet
            //SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from SalesLT.Customer", connection);
            //masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Customers");

            //Dodaj podatke iz tabele Kupci u DataSet
            SqlDataAdapter detailsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select SalesOrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, TotalDue from SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader", connection);
            detailsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Orders");

            //Dodaj podatke iz tabele Narudzbe u DataSet
            SqlDataAdapter dg3DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID, ProductID, OrderQty, UnitPrice, LineTotal from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail", connection);
            dg3DataAdapter.Fill(data, "OrderItems");

            //Povezi Kupce i Narudzbe
            //DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("CustomerOrders",
            //    data.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
            //    data.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"]);
            //data.Relations.Add(relation);

            //Vezi dg1 data connector za tabelu Customers
            //masterBindingSource.DataSource = data;
            //masterBindingSource.DataMember = "Customers";

            //Vezi dg2 data connector za dg1 data connector i filtriraj informacije
            //u dg2 preko DataRelation preko trenutnog reda u dg1.
            //detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
            //detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "CustomerOrders";

            //Povezi Narudzbe i Detalje Narudžbi
            DataRelation relation1 = new DataRelation("OrdersOrderItems",
                data.Tables["Orders"].Columns["SalesOrderID"],
                data.Tables["OrderItems"].Columns["SalesOrderID"]);
            data.Relations.Add(relation1);

            //Vezi dg1 data connector za tabelu Narudzba
            detailsBindingSource.DataSource = data;
            detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "Orders";

            //Vezi dg2 data connector za dg1 data connector i filtriraj informacije
            //u dg2 preko DataRelation preko trenutnog reda u dg1.
            dg3BindingSource.DataSource = detailsBindingSource;
            dg3BindingSource.DataMember = "OrdersOrderItems";

        }

        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nesto nije u redu u zahtijevanju podataka iz baze!");
        }
    }
}}
```

I have commented out my "Monkey See Monkey Do" attempt to make it work with 3 tables and 2 DataRelations and parts where I am getting logical errors (like when I uncomment these lines stuff break and program builds with no errors and runs but doesn't show main window-Form1, so I can't see anything).

I have to say that when I try to relate Customers to Orders only, without OrderDetails, it does not work either (so the code is the same like I have posted here, but only two tables are Customers and Orders). My point is: Maybe it is not approach that is not working but relation between tables in database is a problem. Database used is AdventureWorksLT2012. My software is SQL Server 2014 Enterprise and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Thank you in forward and sorry if my English is bad, it is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it! I hope this can help some other newbies. Solution was to use Stored Procedures...

Result:

[image: 3 Tables bound in 3 DataGridViews]

Here is the code (complete)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InvoiceSQL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private BindingSource masterBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private BindingSource detailsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private BindingSource dg3BindingSource = new BindingSource();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dg1.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
            dg2.DataSource = detailsBindingSource;
            dg3.DataSource = dg3BindingSource;
            getData();

            dg1.AutoResizeColumns();
            dg2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            dg3.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

        }

        private void getData()
        {
            try
            {
                //Odredi string za konekciju
                String connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT2012;Integrated Security=True";
                //Konektuj se na bazu
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                //Odredi novi dataset
                DataSet data = new DataSet();

                data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                //Dodaj podatke iz tabele Kupci u DataSet
                SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("exec dbo.uspGetCustomerCompany", connection);
                masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Customers");

                //Dodaj podatke iz tabele Kupci u DataSet
                SqlDataAdapter detailsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("exec dbo.uspGetOrdersShort", connection);
                detailsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Orders");

                //Dodaj podatke iz tabele Narudzbe u DataSet
                SqlDataAdapter dg3DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("exec dbo.uspGetOrderDetailsShort", connection);
                dg3DataAdapter.Fill(data, "OrderItems");

                //Povezi Kupce i Narudzbe
                DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("CustomerOrders",
                    data.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
                    data.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"]);
                data.Relations.Add(relation);

                //Vezi dg1 data connector za tabelu Customers
                masterBindingSource.DataSource = data;
                masterBindingSource.DataMember = "Customers";

                //Vezi dg2 data connector za dg1 data connector i filtriraj informacije
                //u dg2 preko DataRelation preko trenutnog reda u dg1.
                detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
                detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "CustomerOrders";

                //Povezi Narudzbe i Detalje Narudžbi
                DataRelation relation1 = new DataRelation("OrdersOrderItems",
                    data.Tables["Orders"].Columns["SalesOrderID"],
                    data.Tables["OrderItems"].Columns["SalesOrderID"]);
                data.Relations.Add(relation1);

                //Vezi dg2 data connector za dg1 data connector i filtriraj informacije
                //u dg2 preko DataRelation preko trenutnog reda u dg1.
                dg3BindingSource.DataSource = detailsBindingSource;
                dg3BindingSource.DataMember = "OrdersOrderItems";

            }

            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nesto nije u redu u zahtijevanju podataka iz baze!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```